# Discord Python Bot name MyClient is not defined

Tags: python, discord

Im Programming a discord bot in Python i did the first step but i get the error 
NameError: name'MyClient' is not defined

```
import discord
#Einloggen
class auth(discord.Client):
  async def on_ready(self):
    print("Bot is logged in!")

#Wenn Nachricht 
async def on_message(self, message):
  print("Message from  " + message.author + " contains " + message.content)

client = myclient()
client.run("My Token")
```

In My File my token is pasted in
Can maybe anyone haelp me and say me what is wrong

Comment: and MyClient is written right i checked it

Comment: Nothing in the code has a definition for `myclient()`. Did you mean `discord.Client()`? Or `auth()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already inherited the `discord.Client` class so you don't need `client = myclient()`.

Your client name is `auth` so you have to use `auth.run()`.

Your event listeners `on_ready()` and `on_message` need to be on the same level.

Also `on_message()` doesn't have `self`, just `message`

Here is the completed code:

```py
import discord

class auth(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot is logged in!")

    async def on_message(message):
        print("Message from  " + message.author + " contains " + message.content)

auth.run("My Token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to decorate your function with `@client.event`. We all miss a simple error like that all the time ;).

```py
import discord
#Einloggen
class auth(discord.Client):
  async def on_ready(self):
    print("Bot is logged in!")

#Wenn Nachricht
@auth.event #HERE
async def on_message(self, message):
  print("Message from  " + message.author + " contains " + message.content)

client = auth()
client.run("My Token")
```

Comment: Move the client definition before the `on_message` function

Comment: now i get the error "NameError: name 'MyClient' is not defined"